# Handle BigInt numbers directly from a response without any loss

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bigint

A 3rd party server is returning id's (large number) in int instead of string format, and my server being in Node JS accepts the incoming object that contains the id, and when I use it or print it, I get a different number.

Problem:

```
const num = 2577165522874239503;
console.log(num); // -> gives off '2577165522874239500'
```

While using BigInt:

```
x = 2577165522874239503n;
console.log(BigInt(x).toString()); // -> gives off '2577165522874239503'
```

This approach works, but how to add the n to the number without the server saving the response and causing some losses?
NOTE: The payload is coming from a different server as a HTTP response

JavaScript Wizards please come to the rescue.

I need to accurately store the id as string '2577165522874239503' when the server gives response as an object

```
{
    id : 2577165522874239503,
    username : 'Gandalf'
}
```

Comment: you should use stringds

Comment: If it's coming over http, it's a string at some point. Who's parsing the response? See the "reviver" function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Is that backend under your control? If yes, refactor it  so it will return the `id` as a string and not a number.

Comment: Side note: `x = 257n; console.log(BigInt(x))` is as useless as `Number(42)` or `String("abc")`: `257n` is already a BigInt, sending it through a to-BigInt conversion is a waste of time.

Comment: @danh: the "reviver" can't restore BigInts because it doesn't have access to the original text representation of the value; it needs https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source for that. In the meantime, passing the values as strings (as derpirscher suggests) is the best option.